# NestJS address already in use :::3000

Tags: node.js, typescript, cpanel, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy my NestJs server on a C-Panel hosting. The node_modules are installed properly same as every other file of the project. Everytime I'm trying to run the server it keeps sending me this error: 
`address already in use :::3000`

this is my main.ts file:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as config from 'config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const serverConfig = config.get('server');
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  app.enableCors();

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

As you can see the server port is listening to the environment variable named **PORT** which I'm creating at the C-Panel and if it's not exist it listens to port 3000.

Iv'e looking for three days now for solutions and didn't find one...
Can someone explain to me what causes this error and how to avoid it?

Maybe there is a way of making the server inject a port to the node app?

Comment: Cause of the error: You already have some other program running on your computer which is listening on port 3000.

Comment: yup. Also why C-panel? if their server causes you issues, perhaps you could try something more conventional and better tested? If it's just a small app for your own needs, Heroku would be much more convenient

Comment: @KamilJanowski You right, but I already paid for it so I ain't stop trying to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that on the server that you got from hosting 3000 port is free to use?

If it is safe, you can kill an app that captured 3000 port with the command: `fuser -n tcp -k 3000`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not free because it is not private server and I don't have a terminal to type this command. how can I find an unused port?

Comment: `netstat -peanut` displaying all used ports. So you can choose from 1000 to 65535 and not from that list.

Comment: I''m on C-panel I don't think I got somewhere to type this command.